# Are functions called 'periodic' only if they repeat on $x\in \mathbb{R}$ .

Tags: calculus, functions, periodic-functions

I got that doubt when I came across the following problem.

> Let $f(x)=\min(\{x-1\},\{1-x\}) \enspace\forall  x  \in  [-3,3]$, where $\{x\}$ represents the fractional part of $x$.Then which of the following is true:

1. $ƒ(x)$ is a continuous function $\forall  x  \in [-3,3]$
2. $ƒ(x)$ is a periodic function
3. $\int_{-3}^3f(x)\,dx=\frac32$
4. $ƒ(x)$ is an even function.

This is how solved.
Following is the graph of the function.
[image]

Now option 1),3) and 4) are correct.
***But the author says that option 2) is incorrect, which leads me to a conclusion(doubt) that are function said to be periodic if and only if they are repeating in $x\in \mathbb{R}$. As it is obvious from the graph of the function that it is periodic I would like to know whether my reasoning and the author are correct?***

Comment: This is not periodic.  $f(2.5)\neq f(2.5+1)$.  You could say that $f(x)$ can be extended to a periodic function on all of $\mathbb R$, but of course that is true for any function defined on a finite interval.  You could also say that $f(x)=f(x+1)$ for any $x$ such that *both* $x, x+1$ lie in  $[-3,3]$ (equivalently, $x\in [-3,2]$).

Comment: Well if there was any doubt as to whether this is a good question we now have two opposite answers within ten seconds of each other!

Comment: @ David C. Ullrich,  what I mean by reaping is , graphically a small piece of a function can be repeated to generate the entire function  if the function is periodic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the one hand: A function $f$ is periodic if there is a $P$ that, for all $x$ in the domain, $f(x) = f(x+P)$.  In this case $P$ looks like it should be $1$, but $f(x) = f(x+1)$ is not always true, because there if $x>2$ then $x+1$ is not also part of the domain and so $f(x+1)$ isn't even defined.  Therefore, **the function is not periodic**.

On the other hand, it is true that there is a number $P$ that is some smallish portion of the whole domain such that $f(x) = f(x+P)$ and both $x$ and $x+P$ are in the domain, so I would say that this function is *periodic within its domain*, which is different from being generically periodic, so the answer to the question is still **no**, but this property (which has its own name) is still a thing that might be useful to have sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with actual definition of function.

Comment: Note that just not having all of $\mathbb R$ as its domain isn't enough to defeat periodicity!  $\tan(x)$ and $\sqrt{\sin(x)}$ are both periodic despite missing some of the real line; $\exp(z)$ is not periodic along the real line but does have a period of $2\pi i$.

Comment: @ Dan Uznanski . Yes, I see.